# how to store values in an empty 2d array in php with 20x20 size 2d array

Tags: php

How can I store values in an empty 2d array?
here is my code. Please tell me what is wrong with the code I'm an newbie trying to learn PHP. Thanks!

```
$array2d = array(array());
```

How can I store data make it a `20x20` array?

Comment: If you keep it empty what would be wrong? Why `20x20`?

Comment: Hello sir! I trying insert a random word and insert it to a 20x20 grid.  I think I can only achieve it if I create a 20x20 2d array.

Comment: No need.. Just do loop and assign the random word.

Comment: because i want to position it diagonally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's nothing between the lines and all you're asking is how to create an empty 20x20 array, this is the way to do it:

```
$array2d = array_fill(0, 20, array_fill(0, 20, null));
```

To break that down, the inner `array_fill()` creates a one-dimensional array with 20 items, which are all `null` (replace that with any value you want). The outer `array_fill()` then creates a one-dimensional array filled with 20 arrays created with the inner function.

To set a value to a given index:

```
$array2d[5][12] = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you sir that helps! ^_^